# Cannot resolve symbol for MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I am trying to request permission for ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION and keep getting the error 'Cannot Resolve Symbol 'MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION', here is my code, does anyone know what the issue is?

```
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)){
                checkSelfPermission("Accept this to use location functionality");
            }
            else{
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(GpMap.this,
                        new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                        MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not defined `MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` as an `int` value anywhere in this Java class.